# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined is being listed in my browser console

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, web-applications

I'm currently trying to route my login page to another page using Angular 8, but it is giving me this error in my browser console. 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at LoginComponent.push../src/app/login/login.component.ts.LoginComponent.login (login.component.ts:30)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="login-grid">
  <div></div>
  <form class="login-form box-shadow">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label  for="exampleInputEmail1">User Name</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="User Name">
    </div>
    <div  class="form-group">
      <label  for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password"  type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember Me?</label>
    </div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="login(creds)">Login</button>
  </form>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Typescript Code:

```
export interface IUser {
  id?: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user: IUser = { username: null, password: null };

  constructor(private router: Router, private toastService: ToastService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  login(user: IUser) {
    console.log('this user is ', user);
    const presetUser = { username: 'admin', password: 'password' };

    if (user.username != null && user.password != null &&
      user.username !== '' && user.password !== '') {
      // log the user in
      console.log('from within if statement...');
      this.router.navigate(['contacts', user]);
      if (user.username === presetUser.username &&
        user.password === presetUser.password) {
        // log the user into contacts page
        // saving data to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        // navigate to contacts page
        this.router.navigate(['contacts', user]);
      } else {
        this.toastService.showToast('warning', 2000, 'Username or password is wrong!');
      }

    } else {
      console.log('Must specify credentials');
      this.toastService.showToast('danger', 2000, 'Must specify credentials');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you see where you console.log user?

Comment: @R.Richards Tried that, it does not work.

Comment: @Steve it says "this user is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The user is undefined because when you submit the form you have this:

```
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="login(creds)">Login</button>
```

But `creds` isn't anything so you're getting the undefined error.
You have already defined user as a variable in the code file so this will work:

```
login() {
    console.log('user', this.user);
}
```

This.user is what is linked to the ngModels in the html.

Comment: The console did give me this user is  {username: "admin", password: "password"} however it is still giving me the error  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined.

Comment: Great, so problem solved? Or is there something else you want help with?

Comment: It should have navigated me to the contacts page, but unsure why it is still giving me that error when the user is already defined.

Comment: Have you followed my answer? You need to be referring to this.user not user, as user (if you're still passing that into the function as a parameter which isn't needed) is undefined. If you've made any changes to you code, update your question please